# Why does hash() method return short Hash value with int in Python?

Tags: python, hash, types

When `hash()` method is called in Python 3, I noticed that it doesn't return a long-length integer when taking in `int` data type but with `string` type.

Is this supposed to work this way? If that actually is the case, for the `int` type to have a short hash value, won't it cause collision since it's too short?

```
for i in [i for i in range(5)]:
    print(hash(i))

print(hash("abc"))
```

The Result:

```
0
1
2
3
4
4714025963994714141
```

Comment: What `hash` does is implementation-dependent; don't make any assumptions about what it returns.

Comment: Collisions are inevitable; larger tables reduce collisions, but waste more space.

Comment: just to clarify: `hash` is not a cryptographic hash. if you are interested in those use [`hashlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html?highlight=hashlib). the built-in [`hash`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=hash#hash) is just about unique identifiers.

Comment: The purpose of this value is to distribute keys into dictionary buckets -- it's not intended to be used for purposes that require longer output or stronger guarantees; given its primary use case, the main design goal is speed (since every lookup requires calculating the hash for the key).

Comment: BTW, code formatting should be used, for, well, *code*. `a long-length integer` isn't code, it's English prose; likewise for `short hash value`. If you want to emphasize prose, italics are usually the right choice. See [Highlighting technical words?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155904/highlighting-technical-words) on [meta.se].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In CPython, default Python interpreter implementation, built-in `hash` is done in [this way](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Python/pyhash.c):

> For numeric types, the hash of a number x is based on the reduction
>      of x modulo the prime P = 2**_PyHASH_BITS - 1.  It's designed so that
>      hash(x) == hash(y) whenever x and y are numerically equal, even if
>      x and y have different types

`_PyHASH_BITS` is `61` (64-bit systems) or `31` (32-bit systems)(defined [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Include/pyhash.h))

So on 64-bit system built-in `hash` looks like this function:

```
def hash(number):
    return number % (2 ** 61 - 1)
```

That's why for small ints you got the same values, while for example `hash(2305843009213693950)` returns `2305843009213693950` and `hash(2305843009213693951)` returns `0`

Answer (score 4):

The only purpose of the `hash` function is to produce an integer value that can be used to insert an object into a dict. The only thing `hash` guarantees is that if `a == b`, then `hash(a) == hash(b)`. For a user-defined class `Foo`, it is the user's responsibility to ensure that `Foo.__eq__` and `Foo.__hash__` enforce this guarantee.

Anything else is implementation-dependent, and you shouldn't read anything into the value of `hash(x)` for any value `x`. Specifically, `hash(a) == hash(b)` is allowed for `a != b`, and `hash(x) == x` is not required for any particular `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use hashlib module:

```
>>> import hashlib()
>>> m.update(b'abc')
>>> m.hexdigest()
```