# In python why hash() function return the exact input value when given an int

Tags: python, hash, cpython

When play with the `hash()` in python, find that give an int (less then 18 digit), `hash()` will return the exact same value inputted. It does not make much sense for me.

Why it is designed like this?

Also another interesting thing is that when give `-1` or `-2` it will return `-2` (i.e. a collision)

```
>>> hash(2)
2
>>> hash(1)
1
>>> hash(0)
0
>>> hash(-1)
-2
>>> hash(-2)
-2
>>> hash(-3)
-3
```

*python version is 3.6.12*

Edited:

The point is why it is designed like this, instead of something like md5. to make `hash(x)!=x` even for integer?

Comment: [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#hash)

Comment: The reasoning is also [laid out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194244/why-does-hash-method-return-short-hash-value-with-int-in-python). Pick a _large_ integer in absolute value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does hash() method return short Hash value with int in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194244/why-does-hash-method-return-short-hash-value-with-int-in-python)

Comment: The reason for the weirdness with `-1` is that `-1` is a reserved value to indicate an error in the hashing function at the C layer. A user-defined `__hash__` that returns `-1` is changed to `-2` as well (user-defined functions indicate an error by raising an exception). I don't believe the language requires this, it's just how it works on the CPython reference interpreter to simplify C-layer error-checking.